# ant task to generate swagger jsons on build

Tags: swagger

We are trying to use swagger jaxrs in our app.  We have several problems with the install, but we have narrowed all of them down to the fact we use Websphere and IBM build a custom JVM for WAS that rebuilt the classloader system.  That custom JVM is causing all kinds of headaches with Swagger.

We would like to switch from the servlet depoyment style to simply dropping the JSON files into our web folder of the WAR.  We need this to happen automatically as our CI server builds the deployment, but here are our problems:

1. Maven is strictly forbidden on our network.  So these swagger codegen wrappers won't work
2. Our build language is straight Ant

Now I have looked at the codegen, but it appears that codegen is intended to generate clients from the json files.  I need something that can parse the swagger jaxrs annotations in the code and generate the json files automatically.  manual editing of those files are not an option due to the fact the whole reason we are trying to implement swagger is to eliminate the human need of updating documentation.

Is there a way that I can hook directly into the swagger jaxrs core and generate these json files from an ant task?

Comment: Have you solved your problem ?

Comment: No, Swagger 1.5 they switched from Scala to Java.  That seems to have helped a lot, but its still not perfect.  I havn't worked on this for a while tho.